# Why is the graph incomplete?

Tags: logarithms, graphing-functions

I've put this formula in google: `log(2x-3)`

And it draws this graph: [link to graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3n2A.png)

Why is the graph not being drawn all the way down?
It is supposed to follow the asymptote x = 1.5 right?

Comment: The graph is not drawn "all the way down" because the computer screen you are looking it on is a finite thing, and the graph goes down infinitely...

Comment: Why should $x=4$ be an asymptote for that graph?

Comment: It seems to me that that graph passes **right through** the line $\{x=4\}$.

Comment: Oops I ment x = 1.5
@5xum When I scroll down, it wont draw it either. It just stops at around y = 8

Comment: Because machine precision is finite and because you use a poor graphing software.

Comment: It stops at around $y=8$ because it didn't draw an infinite number of points. Good graphing software would re-draw the line once you scroll.